# Function with for loop - game dice

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I create this function in order to have a random number for my first dice game.

```
function rollDice() {
      return Math.floor(Math.random()*6 + 1);
}
```

Now I want create a new function dices() with a for loop in order to use how much dices the user need.

Usually I used length in a loop as this example:

```
for (var i=1; i < dices.length; i++) {
    // do something
}
```

How you got any suggestions on how to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: To fix what? There is no question.

Comment: How to fix what? What is the problem? You can replace `dices.length` with any number. If you have the number `3` in the variable `numberOfDice` you can replace `dices.length` with `numberOfDice` and the loop will run twice.

Comment: Also, be careful of 0-based "stuff"....

Comment: BTW beware there is a small chance to get 7 due to numbers representation. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#Examples

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's really what you're looking for, but you can simply create a function and replace dice.length by the number of time you want to roll, see this example:

```
function rollManyDice(number) {

    var diceNumber = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        diceNumber += rollDice();
    }

    return diceNumber;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this function if I understand your question? It returns an array with the results from the number of dices thrown.

```
function throwDice(num) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0, l = num; i < l ; i++) {
    arr.push(rolldice());
  }
  return arr;
}

throwDice(3); // e.g. [3, 5, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function rollDice(sides, amount){
  var results = [];
  for (var i=0; i < amount; i++){
    results.push( Math.floor(Math.random()*sides + 1) );
  }
  return results;
}
```

should return a array of how ever amount of dice with the specified number of sides.